# DotSpatial reprojection introduces offset compared with QGIS

Tags: qgis, geojson, c#, dotspatial

Im writing a converter from shape file to Geojson using C# and `DotSpatial` to do coordinate conversion. Currently this mostly works, with newly created shape files in QGIS the coordinates are perfect but when it comes to other files not made by me there is always an offset.

They are using this .prj

```
PROJCS["OSGB_1936_British_National_Grid",GEOGCS["GCS_OSGB 1936",DATUM["D_OSGB_1936",SPHEROID["Airy_1830",6377563.396,299.3249646]],PRIMEM["Greenwich",0],UNIT["Degree",0.017453292519943295]],PROJECTION["Transverse_Mercator"],PARAMETER["latitude_of_origin",49],PARAMETER["central_meridian",-2],PARAMETER["scale_factor",0.9996012717],PARAMETER["false_easting",400000],PARAMETER["false_northing",-100000],UNIT["Meter",1]]
```

That I am importing and converting coordinates like so:

```
private ProjectionInfo fromProjection;
private ProjectionInfo toProjection = KnownCoordinateSystems.Geographic.World.WGS1984;
private Encoding encoder = Encoding.ASCII;

public ShpPrj(byte[] prjFile)
{
    fromProjection = ProjectionInfo.FromEsriString(encoder.GetString(prjFile));
}

public ShpPoint Convert(ShpPoint point)
{
    var data = new double[] { point.X, point.Y };
    var z = new double[] { 1 };

    Reproject.ReprojectPoints(data, z, fromProjection, toProjection, 0, 1);

    return new ShpPoint { X = data[0], Y = data[1] };
}
```

It results in this offset:

[image]

Anyone know what could be the issue?

Comment: what are you using for the transform from OSGB to WGS84 - QGIS will use a grid shift by default

Comment: The transform is all in the code above, DotSpatial is handeling the transformation from OSGB to WGS84 based on the .prj file.

Comment: then that is the problem - Qgis is using a different definition which makes use of at least towgs84 parameters and probably a grid shift file for better accuracy.

Answer (score 1):

You need to ensure you're using the OSTN15 transformation from Ordnance Survey if you're going from OSGB to WGS84.

In my experience DotSpatial doesn't use this which results in the shift you're seeing. QGIS does I believe out of the box.

Details here: https://www.ordnancesurvey.co.uk/business-government/tools-support/os-net/for-developers

Can't help getting DotSpatial to see the .gsb file though, I'm having that issue myself.